# What does "mro()" do?

Tags: python, method-resolution-order

What does [`mro()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=mro#class.__mro__) do?

---

Example from [`django.utils.functional`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/utils/functional.py):

```
for t in type(res).mro():  # <----- this
    if t in self.__dispatch:
        return self.__dispatch[t][funcname](res, *args, **kw)
```

Comment: http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro

Answer (score 273, accepted):

Follow along...:

```
>>> class A(object): pass
... 
>>> A.__mro__
(<class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>)
>>> class B(A): pass
... 
>>> B.__mro__
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>)
>>> class C(A): pass
... 
>>> C.__mro__
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>)
>>>
```

As long as we have single inheritance, `__mro__` is just the tuple of: the class, its base, its base's base, and so on up to `object` (only works for new-style classes of course).

Now, with *multiple* inheritance...:

```
>>> class D(B, C): pass
... 
>>> D.__mro__
(<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>)
```

...you also get the assurance that, in `__mro__`, no class is duplicated, and no class comes after its ancestors, save that classes that first enter at the same level of multiple inheritance (like B and C in this example) are in the `__mro__` left to right.

Every attribute you get on a class's instance, not just methods, is conceptually looked up along the `__mro__`, so, if more than one class among the ancestors defines that name, this tells you where the attribute will be found -- in the first class in the `__mro__` that defines that name.

Comment: hi,alex,is there any difference between D.__mro__ and D.mro().

Comment: `mro` can be customized by a metaclass, is called once at class initialization, and the result is stored in `__mro__` -- see http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=mro#class.__mro__ .

Comment: Why is it called **method resolution order** instead of **attribute resolution order**?

Comment: Just like @Alex Martelli said and the content of  http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html, the __mro__ attribute should be add when the new class are used, as only when Python 2.2 MRO and Python 2.3 MRO(C3) are used.

Answer (score 103):

`mro()` stands for [**Method Resolution Order**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__).  It returns a list of types the class is derived from, in the order they are searched for methods.

`mro()` and `__mro__` work only on new style classes. In Python 3, they work without any issues. In Python 2, however, those classes need to inherit from `object`.

Answer (score 20):

This would perhaps show the order of resolution.

```
class A(object):
    def dothis(self):
        print('I am from A class')

class B(A):
    pass

class C(object):
    def dothis(self):
        print('I am from C class')

class D(B, C):
    pass

d_instance = D()
d_instance.dothis()
print(D.mro())
```

The output would be:

```
I am from A class
[<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class 'object'>]
```

The rule is depth-first, which in this case would mean `D`, `B`, `A`, `C`.

Python normally uses a **depth-first** order when searching inheriting classes, but when two classes inherit from the same class, Python removes the first mention of that class from the MRO.

Comment: So as you can see the order is D, B, A, C

Comment: What do you mean by "Python removes the first mention of that class from mro."?

Comment: @RuthvikVaila: I think that part is just poorly stated. In this [blog post](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html) about the history of Python, Guido van Rossum remarks (about the MRO scheme introduced in Python 2.2) "If any class was duplicated in this search, all but the **last** occurrence would be deleted from the MRO list" (emphasis mine). This implies that it could remove more than just the first "mention" of the class.

Answer (score 3):

Order of resolution will be different in diamond inheritance.

```
class A(object):
    def dothis(self):
        print('I am from A class')


class B1(A):
    def dothis(self):
        print('I am from B1 class')
    # pass


class B2(object):
    def dothis(self):
        print('I am from B2 class')
    # pass


class B3(A):
    def dothis(self):
        print('I am from B3 class')


# Diamond inheritance
class D1(B1, B3):
    pass


class D2(B1, B2):
    pass


d1_instance = D1()
d1_instance.dothis()
# I am from B1 class
print(D1.__mro__)
# (<class '__main__.D1'>, <class '__main__.B1'>, <class '__main__.B3'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)


d2_instance = D2()
d2_instance.dothis()
# I am from B1 class
print(D2.__mro__)
# (<class '__main__.D2'>, <class '__main__.B1'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B2'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Comment: but why the resolution is different ?

Comment: In the multiple inheritance scenario, any specified attribute is searched first in the current class. If not found, the search continues into parent classes in depth-first, left-right fashion without searching same class twice.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand why in first case it's go to `class B3` but in second case it's go to `class A` after `class B1`

Answer (score -1):

For @stryker 's example, the C3 algorithm is:

```
L[D(B,C)] = D + merge(BAo, Co, BC)
          = D + B + merge(Ao, Co, C)
          = DB + A + merge(o, Co, C)
          = DBA + merge(Co, C)
          = DBACo
```

See [The Python 2.3 Method Resolution Order | Python.org](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/#examples)