# python multiple inheritance from different paths with same method name

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

With the following code sample, can `super` be used, or `C` has to call `A.foo` and `B.foo` explicitly?

```py
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print("A.foo()")


class B(object):
    def foo(self):
        print("B.foo()")


class C(A, B):
    def foo(self):
        print("C.foo()")
        A.foo(self)
        B.foo(self)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`super()` will only ever resolve a single class type for a given method, so if you're inheriting from multiple classes and want to call the method in both of them, you'll need to do it explicitly. *i.e.*`A.foo(self)`

Comment: While explicitly calling the base class methods *can* work for very simple scenarios like the questioner's example, it will break down if the base classes themselves inherit from a common base and you don't want the ultimate base class's method to be called twice. This is known as "diamond inheritance" and it is a big problem for many multiple inheritance systems (like in C++). Python's collaborative multiple inheritance (with `super()`) lets you solve easily it in many cases (though that's not to say a cooperative multiple inheritance hierarchy is easy to design or always a good idea).

Comment: Please give an example of how to "do it explicitly"

Comment: @Jonathan `A.foo(self)` is an explicit call to A's foo()

Answer (score 35):

`super` is indeed intended for this situation, but it only works if you use it consistently. If the base classes don't also all use `super` it won't work, and unless the method is in `object` you have to use something like a common base class to terminate the chain of `super` calls.

```
class FooBase(object):
    def foo(self): pass

class A(FooBase):
    def foo(self):
        super(A, self).foo()
        print 'A.foo()'

class B(FooBase):
    def foo(self):
        super(B, self).foo()
        print 'B.foo()'

class C(A, B):
    def foo(self):
        super(C, self).foo()
        print 'C.foo()'
```

@Marcin asks why there has to be a common base:

Without `FooBase` that implements `foo` but doesn't call `super()` the last class that does call `super()` will get an attribute error as there is no base method to call.

If there were separate base classes `class A(AFooBase):` and `class B(BFooBase):` the `super()` call in `A` would call the method in `AFooBase` and the method in `B` would never be called. When the base is common to all of the classes it goes to the end of the method resolution order and you can be certain that no matter how the classes are defined the base class method will be the last one called.

Comment: I think this is a much more informative answer than the one accepted. Could you expand on why one needs the common base class to make this work?

Comment: @marcin You don't have to need a common base to make super() work. @duncan is simply demonstrating how super() is even better when dealing with diamond-inheritance. And by the way, the output of calling `C().foo()` will be `B.foo() A.foo(). C.foo()` rather than "A.. B.. C.." order, and the reason is MRO explaining in [Manoj's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3810465/728675)

Comment: @RayLuo This answer literally says that a common base is required

Comment: @Marcin, I updated my answer. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: @Duncan Indeed.

Answer (score 31):

Thanks for all those contributed to this thread.

## To summarize:

- **[The (currently) accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3810460/728675) is inaccurate.** The correct description should be: super() is NOT ONLY good for resolving single inheritance, BUT ALSO multiple inheritance. And the reason is well explained in @blckknght 's comment:

  > While explicitly calling the base class methods can work for very simple scenarios like the questioner's example, it will break down if the base classes themselves inherit from a common base and you don't want the ultimate base class's method to be called twice. This is known as "diamond inheritance" and it is a big problem for many multiple inheritance systems (like in C++). Python's collaborative multiple inheritance (with super()) lets you solve easily it in many cases (though that's not to say a cooperative multiple inheritance hierarchy is easy to design or always a good idea).
- The proper way, as [@duncan pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3810720/728675), is to use super(), but use it consistently.

  > `super` is indeed intended for this situation, but it only works if you use it consistently. If the base classes don't also all use `super` it won't work, and unless the method is in `object` you have to use something like a common base class to terminate the chain of `super` calls.

  ```
  class FooBase(object):
      def foo(self): pass

  class A(FooBase):
      def foo(self):
          super(A, self).foo()
          print 'A.foo()'

  class B(FooBase):
      def foo(self):
          super(B, self).foo()
          print 'B.foo()'

  class C(A, B):
      def foo(self):
          super(C, self).foo()
          print 'C.foo()'

  C().foo()  # Run this
  ```

  But it is also worth to point out that, the method calling order may NOT seem intuitive at the first thought. The result is:

  ```
  B.foo()
  A.foo()
  C.foo()
  ```

  <s>This seemingly strange order</s> The actual calling order is still `C, A, B`, which is based on MRO. In other words,

  > `super()` will call the foo method on the <s>"first"</s> "next" super class. This is based on the Method Resolution Order (`__mro__`) for the class `C`.
  >
  > -- Quoted and modified from [@Manoj-Govindan 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3810465/728675)

  ```
  >>> C.__mro__
  (<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <type 'object'>)
  >>>
  ```
- As a rule of thumb, if you want to travel back to ALL parent methods but do not really care the invoke order, use `super()` consisently. Otherwise, you may choose to explicitly call parent methods in a specific order.
- Do not mix the usage of super() and explicit calling though. Otherwise you will end up nasty duplication like mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3810434/728675).

## UPDATE: If you want to dive deeper...

In short, using `super(...)` consistently in the whole class family will ensure **ALL** same-name methods from ancestors being called once, in the order of [MRO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010692/what-does-mro-do). Such call-ALL-ancestors (rather than [call-only-the-first-candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3810465/728675)) behavior may be conceptually easier to accept, if the method happens to be a `__init__()`, [see example in this blog post](http://pythonomicon.com/?post=Python%20Multiple%20Inhertance%20and%20the%20MRO).

Saying "follow the MRO order" might not be very precise, though. It actually always follows the "grandchild" 's MRO, somehow. It is fascinating to see it in action. The result of following program may not be exactly what you thought it would be. Pay attention to how `A.__mro__` remains same in 2 different calling stack, yet how `super(A, self).name` or `super(A, self).foo()` behave DIFFERENTLY when triggered by `A().foo()` and by `C().foo()`. See the result quoted at the end.

```
class FooBase(object):
    name = "FooBase"
    def foo(self):
        print('         Base.foo() begins')
        print("         My name is: %s" % self.name)
        print("         My super's name is not available")
        print('         Base.foo() ends')

class A(FooBase):
    name = "A"
    def foo(self):
        print('     A.foo() begins')
        print("     My name is: %s" % self.name)
        print("     My super's name is: %s" % super(A, self).name)
        print("     A.__mro__ is %s" % str(A.__mro__))
        super(A, self).foo()
        print('     A.foo() ends')

class B(FooBase):
    name = "B"
    def foo(self):
        print('     B.foo() begins')
        print("     My name is: %s" % self.name)
        print("     My super's name is: %s" % super(B, self).name)
        print("     B.__mro__ is %s" % str(B.__mro__))
        super(B, self).foo()
        print('     B.foo() ends')

class C(A, B):
    name = "C"
    def foo(self):
        print 'C.foo() begins'
        print("My name is: %s" % self.name)
        print("My super's name is: %s" % super(C, self).name)
        print(" C.__mro__ is %s" % str(C.__mro__))
        super(C, self).foo()
        print('C.foo() ends')


print("We will call A.foo()")
A().foo()

print("We will call C.foo()")
C().foo()  # Run this to see how each foo() is called ONLY ONCE
```

And its result from Python 2.7.12 is:

```
We will call A.foo()
     A.foo() begins
     My name is: A
     My super's name is: FooBase
     A.__mro__ is (<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.FooBase'>, <type 'object'>)
         Base.foo() begins
         My name is: A
         My super's name is not available
         Base.foo() ends
     A.foo() ends
We will call C.foo()
C.foo() begins
My name is: C
My super's name is: A
 C.__mro__ is (<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.FooBase'>, <type 'object'>)
     A.foo() begins
     My name is: C
     My super's name is: B
     A.__mro__ is (<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.FooBase'>, <type 'object'>)
     B.foo() begins
     My name is: C
     My super's name is: FooBase
     B.__mro__ is (<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.FooBase'>, <type 'object'>)
         Base.foo() begins
         My name is: C
         My super's name is not available
         Base.foo() ends
     B.foo() ends
     A.foo() ends
C.foo() ends
```

Comment: Actually the method calling order here is `C`, `A`, `B`. It only appears to be `B`, `A`, `C` because each method chains to the next first and only prints its own string when the other returns. If you put the `print` statements before the `super` calls then the order becomes less surprising. Or put prints before before and after.

Comment: Thanks @Duncan for pointing it out. I played with it and documented more finding (if not more confusion) accordingly. LOL

Comment: To avoid any possible confusion, put the `super().<method>` call at the end of your methods. That means if all three classes `A`, `B` and `class C(A, B)` have a method named `foo`, calling it will go through each method fully and in inheritance order. `C.foo()` will execute `(the content of C.foo()); A.foo(); B.foo()`.

Answer (score 12):

Super will call the `foo` method on the "first" super class. This is based on the Method Resolution Order (`__mro__`) for the class `C`.

```
>>> C.__mro__
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <type 'object'>)
>>>
```

Therefore if you call `super(C, self).foo()`, `A.foo` is called. If you change the inheritance order to `class C(B, A):` then this is reversed. The `__mro__` now looks like:

```
>>> C.__mro__
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>)
>>>
```

If you call `super(C, self).foo()` after making this change, `B.foo()` will get called.

Answer (score 7):

If you added the following:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print 'A.foo()'

class B(object):
    def foo(self):
        print 'B.foo()'

class C(A, B):
    def foo(self):
        super(C, self).foo()
        print 'C.foo()'
        A.foo(self)
        B.foo(self)


c = C()
c.foo()
```

Then super(C, self).foo() refers to A.foo

The output is

```
A.foo()
C.foo()
A.foo()
B.foo()
```

[Edit: Include additional information and links]

- [Understanding Python super() with __init__() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/python-super)
- http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=237121

Comment: Yes, that was my question. So super is not meant for this case?

Comment: @sayap : I have edited my answer to include links that are relevant for understanding how super works. It works but it will find A.foo first and if A.foo was not there than B.foo would have been looked into.

Comment: Why would I want to have A.foo() called twice?

Comment: @sayap: This is just an example. That shows that super uses MRO to find the foo to be called. This could be search for A.foo then B.foo. If you have a requirement that both A.foo and B.foo should be called, call the explicitly or else you expect one of the base classes to implement foo then call super(..).foo. In this case, you just expect one of them to implement foo.

Answer (score 2):

As Duncan said above, you can get predictable results especially if you use super() consistently.

The results from the following test were helpful to me:

```
class FooBase(object):
    def foo(self):
        print 'FooBase.foo()'

class A(FooBase):
    def foo(self):
        print 'A.foo() before super()'
        super(A, self).foo()
        print 'A.foo() after super()'

class B(FooBase):
    def foo(self):
        print 'B.foo() before super()'
        super(B, self).foo()
        print 'B.foo() after super()'

class C(A, B):
    def foo(self):
        print 'C.foo() before super()'
        super(C, self).foo()
        print 'C.foo() after super()'
```

This will print out:

```
>>> c = C()
>>> c.foo()
C.foo() before super()
A.foo() before super()
B.foo() before super()
FooBase.foo()
B.foo() after super()
A.foo() after super()
C.foo() after super()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class A:
    def article(self):
        print("Class A")

class B:
    def article(self):
        print("Class B")

class C(A,B):
    def article(self):
        print("Class C ::\n")
        super().article()

x = C()
x.article()
```

## output:

> Class C ::
>
> Class A

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with `super`

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print 'A.foo()'

class B(object):
    def foo(self):
        print 'B.foo()'

class C(A, B):
    def foo(self):
        print 'C.foo()'
        super(C, self).foo() # calls A.foo()
        super(A, self).foo() # calls B.foo()
```

Comment: So what do you gain by calling `super(C, self).foo()` or `super(A, self).foo()` instead of `A.foo()` or `B.foo()`?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see how the classes with same methods are called:-

Here, in method 'feat()' of class D(A,B,C)

super(D, self).feature2() ----> will call the method (feature2) of class A.

super(A, self).feature2() ----> will call the method (feature2) of class B.

super(B, self).feature2() ----> will call the method (feature2) of class C.

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        print("in A Init")

    def feature1(self):
        print("Feature 1-A working")

    def feature2(self):
        print("Feature 2-A working")

class B:

    def __init__(self):
        print("in B Init")

    def feature1(self):
        print("Feature 1-B working")

    def feature2(self):
        print("Feature 2-B working")

class C:

    def __init__(self):
        print("in C Init")

    def feature1(self):
        print("Feature 1-C working")

    def feature2(self):
        print("Feature 2-C working")

    

class D(A,B,C):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("in D init")


    def feat(self):
        super(D, self).feature2()
        super(A, self).feature2()
    
        print('\n\n')

        ### B().feature2() is calling explicitly, but 
        ### super(A, self).feature2() is not.
        
        ### Both will give same result in below,
        ### It will print True below

        print(B().feature2() == super(A, self).feature2())

        print('\n\n')
    
        super(B, self).feature2()
        print(D.__mro__)


a1 = D()
a1.feat()
```

The result is:-

```
in A Init
in D init
Feature 2-A working
Feature 2-B working



in B Init
Feature 2-B working
Feature 2-B working
True



Feature 2-C working
(<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 
'__main__.C'>, <class 'object'>)
```