# Python multiple inheritance property

Tags: python

In the following code C is inherited from A and B so when c.get() is get which classes get method is called can anyone explain this.....

```
class A:
  def get(self):
    print "In A get"

class B:
  def get(self):
    print "In B get"

class C(A,B):
  def __init__(self):
    print "In c init"

c=C()
c.get()
```

Comment: Why don't you run the code and see?

Comment: Also: Which version of python is this? It matters.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810410/python-multiple-inheritance-from-different-paths-with-same-method-name

Comment: The python version is python 2.4

Comment: If you actually tried to run this, you would find that it doesn't work, because none of your methods take a parameter.

Comment: @Marcin: Shouldn't make a difference here. Also, it seems to be Python 2 (although it's not quite valid Python2, either).

Comment: @NiklasB. Isn't method resolution slightly different for old-style classes?

Comment: @Marcin: In this case, the method from `A` will be used in both versions.

Comment: Without self as parameter of get, there is an error no?
With version 2.7.2+ it raised an exception.

Comment: @Jeremy D: Yes, this isn't valid Python as it stands.

Comment: @Jeremy D:Yes it worked with self as the parameter for get().Thanks..

Comment: This has nothing to do with inheritance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it should be from class A.
Because the search is depth-first, left-to-right.

Comment: In theory it should call A method but what is the error that i have mentioned..

Comment: @Rajeev: You forgot to add the `self` parameter to the `get` methods.

Comment: @Rajeev: Seeing that your question seems to be obsolete now, consider accepting this as an answer and get over with it.

Comment: @Niklas B:I would have accepted the answer except.I had a timing constraint on the question.Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

First of all this code is inncorect as it does not have self variables within method declaration. Correct version is:

```
class A:
  def get(self):
    print "In A get"

class B:
  def get(self):
    print "In B get"

class C(A,B):
  def __init__(self):
    print "In c init"

c=C()
c.get()
```

Secondly this will print:

```
In c init
In A get
```

as ordering is defined in [Method Resolution Order (MRO)](http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.3/mro/). Basicall class C will have all methods/attribues of B and then override by all mehods/attribues from A.

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned is clear: your methods are intended to thake a reference to their bound-to object, but they don't.

Change them to

```
def get(self):
```

as they are methods.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be the `A class` method, like emirc say.

The error is given because you have to add `self` parameter to `get` definition, in that way:

```
class A:
 def get(self):
 print "In A get"

class B:
 def get(self):
 print "In B get"

class C(A,B):
 def __init__(self):
 print "In c init"

c=C()
c.get()
```