# Diamond problem in Python: Call method from all parent classes

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, oop

This question is asked by many but almost all gave the same solution which I am already applying.

So I have classes `TestCase`,`B`,`C`, `D` & `E`. Classes `C` & `D` inherit class `B` & class `E` inherits both `C` & `D`. Class `B` inherits `TestCase`.

When I run my code, class `E` is only running with methods for class `C` and ignoring `D` all along. Now my classes go like these:

```
class GenericAuthClass(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        """Create a dummy user for the purpose of testing."""
        # set some objects and variabels

    def _get_authenticated_api_client(self):
        pass

class TokenAuthTests(GenericAuthClass):

    def _get_authenticated_api_client(self):
        """Get token recieved on login."""
        super()._get_authenticated_api_client()
        # make object
        return object

class BasicAuthTests(GenericAuthClass):

    def _get_authenticated_api_client(self):
        """Get token recieved on login."""
        super()._get_authenticated_api_client()
        # make object
        return object

class ClientTestCase(BasicAuthTests, TokenAuthTests):
    def dothis(self):
        return self._get_authenticated_api_client()
```

How can I call method (with same name) in `C` and `D` from `E` like the diamond problem in `C++`? As of now, when I call the certain method using `self.method()` from `E` it only calls that method from `C` and ignores the same method from `D` while I think it should call both methods.

Note that the method doesn't exist in class `E` and my code is working right now without errors but only calling method from `C`.

This seems like a Python question mainly but tagging Django too as `TestCase` class might have something to do with it.

Comment: Could you provide the full traceback and the line where the error happens?  (Probably where you create a `D` `B` or `C` object)

Comment: I have added the complete stack trace. About where I create? I don't create an instance basically `django` does. You can find information about that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/overview/#order-in-which-tests-are-executed). Basically all `TestCase` sub-classes are run first.

Comment: It looks like your `__init__` methods don't match whatever interface `django` expects.  You shouldn't need `__init__` methods anyways, as you aren't actually doing anything in them. In your actual code, is there anything in those `__init__` methods other than calls to their parent `__init__` methods?  If not, you can remove them and the parent method will be used instead automatically.

Comment: I added those methods while trying to fix a problem, the problem was as I also mentioned in question, in my class `D` I call a certain method which does not exist in `D` but exists in `B` and `C`. When I debug, I find that the method is called for class `B` and code works as if `class D(B)` but not for class `C`. It's multiple inheritance, so it should call it for both of the classes in two different instances. Kind of like diamond problem in `C++`. In short, the problem is, `class D(B,C)` acts like `class D(B)`.

Comment: That would require `super().method(some, arguments)` in `B.method`.  Basically, `D` will go up the MRO (Method Resolution Order) and find the first parent class with a method by that name, and use that method.  That method can use `super` to call other methods further up the MRO, but it doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: `D will go up the MRO (Method Resolution Order) and find the first parent class with a method by that name, and use that method.` What if I want `D` to go to `MRO` and instead of stopping at `first parent class`, run that method for all parents one by one? Isn't that the point of multiple inheritance?

Comment: Does the info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810410/python-multiple-inheritance-from-different-paths-with-same-method-name) help you? Check the other answers, not the accepted one. it seems like @PatrickHaugh is correct

Comment: As always, read [super() considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Comment: Tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40187463/10190191) answer but didn't work for me probably because the common base class of `B` and `C`, which is `TestCase` does not have the method I am trying to call and it's a `django` class so I don't think I can add it there.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the return value of `_get_authenticated_api_client` when you're calling it using `super`.  Maybe `GenericAuthClass` can return an unconfigured object that each of the subclasses can modify as necessary before returning to the caller.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh even if I do that, how will it make `ClientTestCase` call `_get_authenticated_api_client` from both parents instead of just one which we are trying to achieve? And I am using that returned value in `ClientTestCase` class in different methods.

Comment: Add some print statements.  I'm pretty sure that `B._get_authenticated_api_client` is calling `C._get_authenticated_api_client`, but because you're not using the result, it isn't changing the output of `B`s method at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40187463/6779307) is correct when it says

> you have to use something like a common base class to terminate the chain of `super` calls.

That means that you need to write your own base class that goes between `B` and `C` and `TestCase` that ends the `super` chain by implementing your additional methods and then not delegating any calls to its parents:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTestBase(TestCase):
    def method1(self, arg):
        pass
    def method2(self, arg1, arg2):
        pass

class B(MyTestBase):
    def method1(self, arg):
        super().method1(arg)
        ...
    def method2(self, arg1, arg2):
        super().method2(arg1, arg2)
        ...

class C(MyTestBase):
    def method1(self, arg):
        super().method1(arg)
        ...
    def method2(self, arg1, arg2):
        super().method2(arg1, arg2)
        ...

class D(B, C):
    pass
```

Comment: Hi! I followed ur method but the problem remained the same. When I called `self.method1()` in `D`, it called `method1()` from `B` but didn't call `method1` from `C`. While I want both to be called.

Comment: Could you add the code that you're using to your question?  Also, the code in my example incorrectly didn't have `self`, you might double check your code for that.