# Make a hashable id for all subclasses of base class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

For Caching/Persistence reasons I'm looking to get unique hashable address for an arbitrarily large tree of subclasses of a base class (which is never created itself). Here's what things look like at the moment:

```
OBJECT_CACHE = dict()

class Base(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # calculate class_addr here?
        obj = OBJECT_CACHE.get(class_addr)
        if obj is None:
            obj = super(Base, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            OBJECT_CACHE[class_addr] = obj
        return obj
```

But I'm not sure what the best way to go about getting such an id would be. My concept is that it would look something like the following:

```
Base:          # no id
    F          # id = 'f'
    A:         # id = 'a'
        E      # id = 'a.e'
        B:     # id = 'a.b'
            C  # id = 'a.b.c'
            D  # id = 'a.b.d'
```

I thought about trying something with properties and `super()` but ideally the subclasses would only contain a single line like `my_id = 'e'`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just use the class object itself?

Comment: @delnan If I understand what you mean, largely because the default hash values are linked to object memory addresses - which would change if the script is stopped and started again. (The `OBJECT_CACHE` could be pickled and saved)

Comment: No, it stores the class name and module name and retrieves whatever is stored in the module of that name with that identifier. Try it out: `class C(object): pass` followed by `import pickle; s = pickle.dumps({C: 1}); C = 'foo'; print pickle.loads(s)`

Comment: ah, good point. I did want to be able to reference the objects in the notation that I noted though (and I'm not ending up using the class.__name__, but rather a different attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [cls.mro()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2010732/190597):

```
OBJECT_CACHE = dict()
class Base(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        class_addr = cls.name()
        obj = OBJECT_CACHE.get(class_addr)
        if obj is None:
            obj = super(Base, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            OBJECT_CACHE[class_addr] = obj
        return obj
    @classmethod
    def name(cls):
        names = [k.__name__.lower() for k in cls.mro() 
                if k != Base and issubclass(k, Base)]
        return '.'.join(names[::-1])


class F(Base): pass
class A(Base): pass
class E(A): pass
class B(A): pass
class C(B): pass
f = F()
a = A()
e = E()
b = B()
c = C()
print(OBJECT_CACHE.keys())
```

yields

```
['a', 'a.e', 'a.b.c', 'a.b', 'f']
```

Comment: `mro()` does seem like the way to go, but what if one of the subs inherits from another class that doesn't inherit from Base? e.g. `class A(Base, str)` Can I check if the classes have a shared base?

Comment: The mro includes all bases, and each base will be included only once. So I think it will work just fine. If you add `str` as a base, then `basestring` is also part of the mro. I don't know if you want to include that or not. If not, just add `basestring` to the tuple of classes to be excluded: `if k not in (Base, object, basestring)`.

Comment: I think we can negate this by checking `issubclass()` for each loop. I'll edit your answer for clarity then accept it.