# How can I sort a list of Python classes by inheritance depth?

Tags: python, class, oop, method-resolution-order

How would I sort a list of classes in Python, making sure that any child class is before any of its parent classes in the list?

I ask because I want to see what type out of a list of types, an object belongs to, but find the most specific type, if it belongs to multiple.

Comment: use `issubclass` in your sort key function.

Comment: (typically: `sorted(classes, cmp=lambda x, y: 1 if issubclass(x, y) else -1)`)

Comment: @njzk2: That comparator is inconsistent; classes with no inheritance relationship each compare less than the other, and a class always compares greater than itself.

Comment: that's just an example on top of my head, not an actual answer.

Comment: There is no simple solution. Python MRO is very picky. See discussion at https://discuss.python.org/t/make-mro-topological-sorted/32300

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply sort by `len(cls.mro())`.

If `C2` is a subclass of `C1`, it must hold that `len(C1.mro()) < len(C2.mro())` (because each class in `C1.mro()` must also appear in `C2.mro()`). Therefore, you can simply sort by the length of the [mro list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010692/what-does-mro-do-in-python):

```
class A(object): pass
class X(object): pass
class B(A, X): pass
class C(B): pass
class D(C): pass

sorted([B, C, A, D, X], key = lambda cls: len(cls.mro()))
=> [__main__.A, __main__.X, __main__.B, __main__.C, __main__.D]
```

To also support old-style classes, you can replace `cls.mro()` with [`inspect.getmro(cls)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmro).

Comment: `cls.__mro__` should be used instead of `cls.mro()` to avoid recomputing MRO, which is expensive.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to use a set and then move along the inheritance tree of the target class.

```
def find_parent(target, class_set):
    if target in class_set:
        return [target]
    else:
        bases = []
        for parent in target.__bases__:
            result = find_parent(parent, class_set)
            if result is not None:
                bases.extend(result)
        return bases
```

Example:

```
class A(object):
    pass

class B(str):
    pass

class C(A):
    pass

class D(A, dict):
    pass

class_set = {dict, A}

print find_parent(A, class_set)
print find_parent(B, class_set)
print find_parent(C, class_set)
print find_parent(D, class_set)
```

Gives you this result:

```
[<class '__main__.A'>]
[]
[<class '__main__.A'>]
[<class '__main__.A'>, <type 'dict'>]
```