# calling super subclass in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

I am trying to understand some basic OOP in python. If I try to subclass a class like list, how do I invoke the parent constructor? After tinkering for a bit I found that it is:

```
super(subclass_name, self).__init__(args).
```

However I dont intuitively understand this. Why can't I just do list(args)? or

```
list.__init__(args)?
```

The following is the relevant snippet:

```
class slist(list):
  def __init__(self, iterable):
    #super(slist, self).__init__(iterable)  <--- This works)
    list.__init__(iterable) # This does not work
    self.__l = list(iterable)

  def __str__(self):
    return ",".join([str(s) for s in self.__l])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.__init__(iterable)` is incorrect. You need to tell `__init__()` which object it is initializing. `list(args)` is even more incorrect, as it creates a completely new list object rather than initializing your object. It calls `list.__new__()` rather than `list.__init__()`. You need to pass `self` to the constructor call to correctly initialize the parent class:

```
list.__init__(self, args)
```

and that would work. Using `super()` though usually allows for cleaner syntax. For example, the above could be rewritten as:

```
super(slist, self).__init__(args)
```

However, the main reason useage of `super()` is encouraged over simply calling the parent constructor, is for cases where you have multiple inheritance. `super()` will automatically call the constructor of each parent class in the correct order. This is closely related to Python's [Method Resolution Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010692/what-does-mro-do-in-python).

Answer (score 4):

`list.__init__(iterable)` is missing the information of *which* list to initialize, and `list(iterable)` builds a different list entirely unrelated to the one you're trying to initialize.

If you don't want to use `super`, you can do `list.__init__(self, iterable)`.