# Python: Overriding method in child class skipping one of the Base Class

Tags: python, class, oop, overriding

I have two base classes `A` and `B` each of them have a method `myfunc`, which prints out a different character.

```py
class A:
    def myfunc(self):
        print('A')

class B:
    def myfunc(self):
        print('B')
```

I have one more `class C` which is inheriting from `A` and `B` both. In `class C` I have overridden `myfunc` and called `super` over it.

```py
class C(B, A):
    def myfunc(self):
        super().myfunc()
```

Now if I execute following code,  it prints only one character

```py
x = C()
x.myfunc()
```

Output:

```
B
```

I tried `print(C.__mro__)` which gives me `(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)` So it should go to `class A` and  print character `A` also. right?

Also if I switch the order of inheritance like `C(A,B)` it and use the same code , it is skipping `class B`.

**My questions:**

1. Why it's skipping `class A`?
2. How to execute  `myfunc` method in both classes `A` and `B`

I looked up  [similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027696/multiple-inheritance-overridden-methods-containing-super-calls) but found it confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering question 1:

It is skipping `myFunc` on class A because what python does when you call `super.myFunc()` is search for the first function with name `myFunc` in all the base classes (in this case `B` and `A`) and it does that in order, so it first look for `myFunc` in class `B`. So, because there is a function named `myFunc` in class `B` python stop searching and executes only that.

Answering question 2:

There is a trivial way of doing that which is this:

```py
class A:
    def f(self):
        print('A')

class B:
    def f(self):
        print('B')

class C(B, A):
    def f(self):
        A.f(self)
        B.f(self)

c = C()
c.f()
```

Basically you can call any function of any class and then pass the instance as the first argument (`self`). I believe you can't execute both functions with only one call, you will need to make a call for each one.