# Calling procedure of multiple inheritance in python

Tags: python

I came across a class inheritance problem in python.

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print("A")

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        print("!B")
        super(B,self).foo()
        print("B")

class C:
    def foo(self):
        print("!C")
        super(C,self).foo()
        print("C")


class D(C,B):
    def foo(self):
        print("!D")
        super(D,self).foo()
        print("D")

bar = D().foo()
```

Why the output is

```
!D
!C
!B
A
B
C
D
```

Is it because class C gets a parent class from class D's inheritance?

Comment: The super call happens based on the `Method Resolution Order`. Which part seems confusing to you ? Try `D.__mro__`

Comment: What did you expect the output to be? What was your reasonining?

Comment: I was expecting `super(C,self).foo()` will throw exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite it's name, `super()` is not calling on "*the*" parent class (which makes no sense since with multiple inheritance you can have more than one single parent class...) but on the next class in [the `__mro__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010692/what-does-mro-do).

In you case, the mro for `D` is `C, B, A`, so `D.foo` will call `C.foo` which will call `B.foo` which will call `A.foo`.

If what puzzles you is that `super(C, self).foo` resolves to `B.foo` even while `C` doesn't inherit from `B`, you have to remember that `super` will use the mro of `self`, which in this case DOES include `B`  since `self` here is a `D` instance, not a `C` instance. That's actually why`super` needs both the current class and the current instance FWIW.

> Is it because class C gets a parent class from class D's inheritance?

Almost... that's not how it works (cf above), but the effective result is quite similar.

> I was expecting super(C,self).foo() will throw exception

It will if the class `super()` resolves too has no `foo` method (or if it has a non-callable `foo` attribute):

```
class E(C):
    def foo(self):
        print("!E")
        super(E,self).foo()
        print("E")

E().foo()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "sup.py", line 65, in foo
    super(E,self).foo()
  File "sup.py", line 50, in foo
    super(C,self).foo()
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

And this comes from the `super(C, self).foo()` call in `C` - in this case, the next class in `E.__mro__` is `object`, which doesn't indeed define a `foo` method ;-)