# Do objects have a copy of their class methods?

Tags: python, class, object, methods, instance

I wanted to know whether an object has a copy of all its class methods. So I created a class `person`, defined a method `getName` and created an object `Harry`. I used `dir` function to check whether both the class and the object have `getName` method stored inside them and both of them returned true. I then printed out the `getName` method of both the class and the object and they returned different addresses, but I noticed that `harry.getName` method is bounded to `person.getName`. So does that mean that `harry.getName` is not a copy of its class method rather just a reference to its class method. To check this used `delattr` method to delete the `getName` attribute of the person class and again used `dir` to check it. And as expected it deleted it from both the class `person` and object `Harry`.

So please review my code and tell whether my thoughts are correct.

Note:

The `dir()` function returns all properties and methods of the specified object, without the values.

The `delattr()` method is used to delete the named attribute from the object, with the prior permission of the object.

[image: Python Code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without going into too much [detail](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), what you are observing is the on-the-fly creation of a function that acts like `person.getName` but the first argument (`self`) is already bound to an instance.

So no, objects do not have a copy of the methods in their class. Every time you access `Harry.getName` a new callable object (the "method") is built from scratch. It behaves like `person.getName` with `self=Harry`.

On the other hand, no new callable is constructed when you access `getName` on the class level.

Answer (score 0):

What I conclude is this:

When we instantiate a class using `variableName = className(args)` it creates an object in memory, initializes all its data attributes using `init` method (constructor) and returns the memory address of the object data to the object variable name and we call it as an instance.

The object data contains two things

1. Data attributes and its values
2. Memory references of its class methods.

Whenever we call any method on the object by `instanceName.method()`, it refers to the class method and passes the object data itself as specified by the `self` argument and execute it to access or modify the object data.

Thus, the object in the memory only contains data attribute values and not a copy of its class methods, but only their memory references.

Comment: You will get pretty far with that mental model. There are some details to add. For example, when you do `instanceName.method()`, `self=instanceName` is not passed to the function `method` in the classes' `__dict__` directly. A brand new callable is built from scratch on the basis of `className.method` each time you access `instanceName.method`. That brand new callable behaves as if `self=instanceName`.

Comment: Also, there are no "memory attributes". When Python can't find an attribute in the `__dict__` of an instance, it will go search for it in other places, starting at the class of the instance.

Comment: @timgeb Oh! So the object doesn't have memory attributes. So, it just searches for the called method in the class of the instance and if not found, it searches for it in its parent classes. Is that how inheritance works?

Comment: @timgeb Your answers are very insightful. Thanks .

Comment: "Is that how inheritance works?" <- [Pretty much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010692/what-does-mro-do)