# what is inheritance and MRO() in python

Tags: python, inheritance

what does the MRO() in inheritance do ?? The python documnetation it's a little bit confusing to understand the topic. so anyone can help me?

Comment: Look at this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010692/what-does-mro-do

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> class Test:
...     def __init__(self,a):
...             self.a=a
...     def sqrt(self):
...             return self.a**0.5
...
>>> t = Test(2)
>>> t.sqrt()
1.4142135623730951
>>> Test.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Test'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> Test.__mro__[0]
<class '__main__.Test'>
>>> Test.__mro__[1]
<class 'object'>
```

You can see your object position, name and also type.