# Understanding Nested Inheritance in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

Here is a simplified code of my main code illustrating the behaviour I obtain.

Suppose I have a main class  (MAIN) and two classes (A,B) inheriting from it. This main class has a method which is overwriten by A but not by B, which means that B inherits the method from main.

Then I have a class D which inherits from A and from B, and has a method which calls the aforementioned method. From what I have understood in the way multiple inheritance work, if I define D as `class D(A,B)`  then if A and B have a shared method, calling D.method() will call A.method, and vice-versa (i.e if `class D(B,A)`  then B.method is called. The following code exemplifies this text.

```py
class MAIN(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def print(self):
        print('HELLO MAIN')

class A(MAIN):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def print(self):
        print('HELLO A')

class B(MAIN):
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def Cprint(self):
        self.print()

c = C()

c.Cprint()


class C(B,A):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def Cprint(self):
        self.print()

c = C()

c.Cprint()
```

However this code always print 'HELLO A', i.e even in the case class `C(B,A)` I don't get a HELLO MAIN as I would expect. What is happening here? Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`mro`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010692/what-does-mro-do) is `(C, A, B, MAIN)` with `class C(A, B)` and `(C, B, A, MAIN)` with `class C(B, A)`. In both cases, `A` is before `MAIN`. `B` doesn't define `.print`, so it doesn't matter.

The method uplooks works like this: (pseudo code)

```
def find_attribute(obj, name):
    if name in obj.__dict__:
        return obj.__dict__[name]
    mro = type(obj).__mro__
    for cls in mro:
        if name in cls.__dict__:
            return cls.__dict__[name] # (Here a bit more magic for descriptors happens)
    raise AttributeError(name)
```

For the classes this is what their `__dict__` look like:

```
MAIN.__dict__ = {"print": <method MAIN.print>}
A.__dict__ = {"print": <method A.print>}
B.__dict__ = {}
C.__dict__ = {"Cprint": <method C.Cprint>}
```

As you can see, `B` does not have a `print` defined, so in `mro=(C, B, A, MAIN)` the first `print` that does get found is in `A`.

Comment: You can call `C.mro()` to see the mro for class `C`.  Note that `C` must be a class, and not a class instance.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes. I decided to no explain that and instead link to the other question. Way better explanation that I don't need to fully duplicate here.

Comment: It's interesting to note that certain inheritance sequences are forbidden.  For example, `class C(A, MAIN)` is allowed, but `class C(MAIN, A)` gives an error, since it cannot create a consistent mro.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just one point. If `B` does not define `.print` then it should inherit MAIN `.print` method, then in the case where the mro is (C, B, A, MAIN), 'HELLO MAIN' should be printed. Am I right?

Comment: @jdeJuan No. `B` does not have a `.print` attribute/method. I will update the answer and fully explain it.

Comment: @jdeJuan In the case where the mro is (C, B, A, MAIN), there are two classes that *directly* define `print`:  A and MAIN.  Since A is before MAIN in the mro, it will use A's `print` method, so you should see `HELLO A`.  Figuring out the mro can be tricky (but Python will tell you, as I explained in my first comment).  But once you know the mro, it's trivial to determine which method it will use.

Comment: thanks for your answers. I thought print will be part of B hence expecting the behaviour I posted. But this provides me a bit more of understanding about how python inheritance works. Didnt expect inherited non-overwritted methods did not take part of the __dict__

Answer (score 0):

You are inheriting the Class A everywhere and class A overrrides Main functions print() thats why you dont get the "HELLO MAIN"

```
class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def Cprint(self):
        self.print()
```

inherit only B class  which does not overrides Main class print function then you will get the HELLO MAIN output