# python multiple inheritance from ancestor and child

Tags: python, inheritance

Consider:

```
   class Base():
      def foo():
          ...

   class A(Base):
      def bar():
          ...

   class MyBase(Base):
      def zee():
          ...
      def bar():
          ...


  class MyA(MyBase, A):
       def zee():
          ...
```

Now I want to introduce `MyA` class which has the property of both `MyBase` and also `A`. Is the way I inroduced `MyA` correct?

```
Base ___
 |      Possible other ancestors
 |      |
MyBase  A
 |      |
 MyA-----
```

Note both `MyBase` and `A` are derived from `Base`, So it refers to `Base` from different paths. I would like to know if there is any considerations or alternative approaches.

For example while `bar` is introduced in `A` and also `MyBase`, if I don't have a `bar` in `MyA`, the `bar` of `Mybase` is considered the overridden method of `A` for `MyA`?!! How could I avoid it? unless I change `MyBase` method name.

Comment: This is a big topic.  I suggest searching for Python multiple inheritance and reading up on it.  In your example, there are no conflicts so it's very simple.  In practice, conflicts do occur, particularly with `__init__`.  In general, you want to call the `__init__` method in your base classes from the `__init__` method in the derived class.  But there may be more than one.  You can use `super()` to help with it.

Comment: If you really want to understand how Python resolves conflicts, you need to read about Python's [Method Resolution Order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/), as described in the preceding link.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks, I also modified it a bit to show some conflicts, like `bar` method, which is both in `MyBase` and `A` wondering which is overrided.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "mro()" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010692/what-does-mro-do)

Comment: @TomKarzes I added a specific problem I encountered now after introducing my classes as above.

Comment: The example keeps changing, which is usually a good indication that the question should be closed.  It's a duplicate, and you have a complete answer in the link I provided.  I know it's a bit complicated, but a simpler explanation will be wrong, or at best incomplete.  If you don't want to understand it, then just avoid multiple inheritance.

Comment: Okay, no problem, however I read the link to some extent and I underestand to some extent, just wanted to assure the whole approuche is good and there isn't other alternative. Also, as you see, I can't avoid multiple inheritance unless I repeat code.

Comment: Take a look at the duplicate SO question link.  One of the answers shows how to actually inspect the mro for a given class.