# How Python's Super() works in multiple inheritance for superclasses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hierarchy, multiple-inheritance, super

I'm trying to understand how super works in python's multiple inheritance for the superclasses, for example in the code below:

```
class First():
    def __init__(self, parm1, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.parm1 = parm1
        self.parm3 = 'one'


class Second():
    def __init__(self, parm2 = 'zero', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.parm2 = parm2

class Third(First,Second):
    def __init__(self,parm1):
        super().__init__(parm1=parm1)


trd = Third('tst')
print(trd.parm1)    # 'tst'
print(trd.parm3)    # 'one'
print(trd.parm2)    # 'zero'
```

If I remove the `super().__init__(**kwargs)` the execution ends with

> 'Third' object has no attribute 'parm2'

printing only the `parm1` and `parm3`,  even if I declared the hierarchy in `Class Third(First,Second)`.

I know all classes inherit from Object class, but I don't understand how it could be involved with the super() class in the parent classes and how the latter allows to access to the second parent's attributes.

Comment: `super()` is the same as `super(__class__, <first argument>)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://realpython.com/lessons/multiple-inheritance-python/

Base classes are applied from left onto right, i.e. the most base class is on the right.

e.g. in `class Third(First,Second)` things from `First` will override things from `Second`. i.e. `Second` is the most base class here. (Judging by the naming, you probably expected the reverse?)

We can also see this by inspecting the "Method Resolution Order" of `Third`:

```py
In [1]: Third.__mro__
Out[1]: (__main__.Third, __main__.First, __main__.Second, object)
```

We can read this tuple as child->parent in left-to-right order. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2010732/202168

Another thing to know is that `super().__init__()` will find a different parent class to call *depending on the context*.

For example `First` does not inherit from `Second`, so if you instantiate a `First` the `super` call will go straight to `object`. We can see this in the MRO:

```py
In [2]: First.__mro__
Out[2]: (__main__.First, object)
```

But when we instantiate a `Third`, that class inherits from both `First` and `Second`... so the `super` call chain will reflect the order in `Third.__mro__`... meaning that the `super` call in `First` will now call the method in `Second` (because `Second` is the next parent class *from the perspective of the child class that initiated the `super` call chain*). And the `super` call in `Second` will call the `__init__` of `object`, where the chain ends.

All this means that if you remove `super().__init__(**kwargs)` from `First` then the chain of super calls is broken before reaching `Second.__init__`.

Hence you get the `AttributeError` *"'Third' object has no attribute 'parm2'"* when you try to `print(trd.parm2)`.

Comment: Ok thanks, so if I understand:
- The order of the overriding is from the right to the left of the class parenthesis
- `super().__init__(**kwargs)` is like a "link" thru the different inheritances, so it is necessary only when there's "horizontal" inheritance

Comment: `super()` returns the 'next' parent class (and that is resolved dynamically depending which is ultimately the 'top' or child class being instantiated) If you want your methods to play nicely in a class hierarchy they should generally use `super()` to call the same method on any parent class that may exist. So in the case of `__init__` method that's nearly always wanted because all classes will have such a method (including the `object` root type)