# python using super(), can't access variable from second parent class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, super

This is probably very simple question. In a child class, which is inherited from two parent classes, I can't access variable from second parent class using super(). Here is my code:

```
class Core:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a_from_Core = 7


class Extra:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b_from_Extra = 90


class Trash(Core, Extra):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        print(self.a_from_Core)     # working
        print(self.b_from_Extra)    # does not work



trashcan = Trash()
```

And here is error:

> AttributeError: 'Trash' object has no attribute 'b_from_Extra'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)

Answer (score 1):

Python uses "cooperative" multiple inheritance (https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

which kinda means all classes involved in the inheritance need to agree to play.

For single inheritance, it just works -- which is what lulled you into thinking it would work for multiple.

You need to add calls to `super().__init__()` in all classes, for example

```
class Core:
  def __init__(self):
    self.a_from_Core = 7
    super().__init__()  # added


class Extra:
  def __init__(self):
    self.b_from_Extra = 90
    super().__init__()  # added

class Trash(Core, Extra):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    print(self.a_from_Core)
    print(self.b_from_Extra)    # works!                                                                                                 

trashcan = Trash()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inheriting from two classes, according to `MRO`, your first father is `Core` and your second father is `Extra`.

So when you call `super`, the `__init__` in `Core` is called and the `__init__` in the `Extra` is not called, so you don't have `b_from_Extra`.

As in `MRO` of `Trash` you have something like: `[..., Core, Extra]`, if you call `super` in `Core`, the method in Extra would be called.

So you can do the following :

```py
class Core:
  def __init__(self):
    self.a_from_Core = 7
    super().__init__()
...
```

You can read about [MRO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010692/what-does-mro-do).