# Multiple Inheritance in Python calling parent methods giving confusing output

Tags: python, methods, multiple-inheritance

Multiple Inheritance in Python calling parent methods

```
class A:
    def m(self):
        print(f"m of A called")
class B(A):
    def m(self):
        print("m of B called")
        super().m()
class C(A):
    def m(self):
        print("m of C called")
        super().m()
class D(B,C):
    def m(self):
        print("m of D called")
        super().m()

x = D()
x.m()
```

Gives the output

> m of D called

> m of B called

> m of C called

> m of A called

Why is m of A only called once? My assumption is that it should be called twice, once by B() and once by C().

I was expecting the A.m() method to be called and printed out twice, but it only shows up once.

Comment: Your code is a common  example of [diamond inheritance problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) and the linearization logic(C3 Method Resolution Order) used by Python to handle this ambiguity is explained really well here: https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "mro()" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010692/what-does-mro-do)

Answer (score 3):

This is the MRO concept of python, I think this article is helpful: [GFG](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-resolution-order-in-python-inheritance/)

In your case, the `mro` is D -> B -> C -> A. Because B and C both use same parent, Python first checks the left class(B), then the class after that(C), then their common parent(A).

You can always check the `mro` by yourself by:

```py
...
print(D.__mro__)
...
```

Comment: +1. A key observation to make from this behavior is that you should avoid this pattern if possible. See `import this` for more details :)

Comment: @flakes I wouldn't necessarily agree. For example, mixins are a case where such behaviour can be used for the benefit of the code. I also don't see anything in Python Zen directly calling this out.

Comment: @matszwecja mixins are fine, especially when defined without a constructor. Complicated method resolution ordering when multiple classes within the tree define the same method is what I'm suggesting to avoid.

Comment: @flakes But that's one of the ways to achieve mixins; each having same method that calls its `super()` will ensure all of those methods are called.

Comment: @matszwecja Typically I find that mixins add functionality to the class without affecting the core behavior, and act mostly as a way to compartmentalize re-usable logic. I would find it unusual to see multiple mixins on a class that would duplicate added methods, complicating your MRO. I have no issue with `super()` or multiple inheritance for that pattern-- My issue is when you have multiple resolvers to a `super()` call which sit on the same level of an inheritance tree, making the ordering of invocations dependent on ordering of parent classes in the subclass definition.

Comment: @flakes if you have mixins that together work to effect programming *hooks*, say `def on_save_validate_data`, then a given type of use case may very well rely on what *you* find to be an antipattern.  Not to say a quick heuristic on a design is not to wonder at complex mro chaining, but there are valid enough reasons, *if one knows what one is doing.*.  Reading a noob’s code replete with it?   Yes, probably a red flag.