# Nested dictionary with class and instance attributes

Tags: python

I store some configuration details across several class attributes and one main class which references each of them. E.g.

```
class A:
    a = 1

class B:
    b = 2   
    def __init__(self):
        self.a_ = A()

x = B()
```

I would like to display all class (and instance) attributes in a dictionary, i.e.

```
{'b': 2, 'a_': {'a': 1}}
```

I understood `__dict__` does not access class attributes.

```
x.__dict__  # {'a_': <__main__.A at 0x1b888d9e530>}
x.__dict__['a_'].__dict__  # {} -- why not {'a': 1}?
```

So I tried below class methods but the result is still not right:

```
    @classmethod
    def to_dict(cls):
        return vars(cls)

    @classmethod
    def to_dict2(cls):
        return cls.__dict__
```

Comment: As you say, class attributes aren't in the instance `__dict__`. The MRE doesn't include `B` at all, `A().__dict__ == {}`. You don't seem to be _calling_ `to_dict` anywhere, so what do you mean _"the result is still not right"_?

Comment: `.__dict__` gives you an objects *namespace*. It isn't accessing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a `Serializable` class that both `A` and `B` inherit from that has a custom method `to_dict()` to achieve your desired output:

```
class Serializable:
    def to_dict(self):
        d = {}
        for key, value in self.__class__.__dict__.items():
            if not key.startswith('__') and not callable(value):
                d[key] = value
        for key, value in self.__dict__.items():
            if hasattr(value, 'to_dict'):
                d[key] = value.to_dict()
            else:
                d[key] = value
        return d


class A(Serializable):
    a = 1


class B(Serializable):
    b = 2

    def __init__(self):
        self.a_ = A()


x = B()
print(x.to_dict())
```

Output for above: `{'b': 2, 'a_': {'a': 1}}`.

Note this approach will have issues if your classes have circular references, non-serializable objects, attributes with leading underscores, or dynamically added attributes.

But it works for your given contrived example!

Comment: Thanks for solution. Just one question: why contrived?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) to chain together attribute mappings of a given object and all classes in the [MRO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010692/what-does-mro-do) of its type. Recursively convert a child object if it has a `__dict__` attribute:

```
from collections import ChainMap

def all_vars(obj):
    return {
        name: all_vars(value) if hasattr(value, '__dict__') else value
        for name, value in ChainMap(*map(vars, (obj, *type(obj).mro()))).items()
        if not (name.startswith('__') and name.endswith('__'))
    }
```

so that:

```
class A:
    a = 1

class B:
    b = 2
    def __init__(self):
        self.a_ = A()

x = B()
print(all_vars(x))
```

outputs:

```
{'b': 2, 'a_': {'a': 1}}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/8omz5u